# Reduce size of image with a fixed div

Tags: image, html, resize

I am allowing users to edit their profile icon,so that the users can adjust their icon to what part of the image to display.

I have a fixed `<div>` with width 50px and height 50px; .This size will be used when users are editing icon.The image will be larger and users can drag and set what to show.In coding part i had taken width,height,top,left.Top and left is used to determine what to show.Hope you understand that.

My problem arises when the edited icon is shown in the top bar. I had set the width of the div as 30px X 30px. When converting 50px size to 30px i had subtracted 20px from the obtained width so that it fits inside the 30px div as expected by the user.The actual part where what part of the image is to be displayed causes problems, the top and left obtained is for 50px div using the top and left for 30px div the expected part is not displayed as you can guess that.

I want to show the part that is selected by the user.Check this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4mDQf/

How can i do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you're getting at. You want to allow users to slice out a specific chunk of an image for use as their icon, rather than just resizing the whole image down to your 30x30 limit?

Answer (score -1):

I had figured out a solution:

Cut the part to be displayed in 50px and shrink the cut image to 30px using php.